# Very confused by the VS2022 code analysis configuration options

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, roslyn-code-analysis

When I build my C# solution in VS2022 I see various code analysis build warnings, for example:

> IDE0090 'new' expression can be simplified

I'd like to change the severity of some of these to "suggestion", which I assume will continue to display the editor squiggle/light bulb but not the build warning. When I click the light bulb next to the line of code, this set of menus appears:
[image]

Could someone explain the difference between the four 'Configure...' menu options please? I.E.

- "Configure IDE0090 code style"
- "Configure IDE0090 severity"
- "Configure severity for all 'Style' analyzers"
- "Configure severity for all analyzers

(The first option provides "true" & "false" choices, while the other three provide "None", "Silent", ...)

I don't know if this is relevant but I have the "StyleCop.Analyzers" package installed in each project in my solution.

As an aside, the "change preview pane" seen on the r.h. side of the image shows it wanting to add the new lines to my .editorconfig file, which lives in the solution's root folder (I've confirmed it is this file, based on the line numbers and last existing lines seen in the preview). However whenever I make a selection it never updates the file (and I continue to see IDE0090 appear as a build warning). Am I missing something? The file isn't read-only!

If I add the lines seen in the preview window to .editorconfig myself via Notepad then the warnings disappear.

Comment: I'd say the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0090) explain it pretty well (severity is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-options#severity-level)). The .editorconfig issue I'm not sure about.

Comment: I understand what the severity levels do, but it's not clear what the difference is between four "Configure..." menu items. Also, your doc link very doesn't really explain what the boolean option does (to me at least). Is it just an alternative way to suppress the warning, instead of setting severity to None?

Comment: There's even a helpful [sample](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0090#csharp_style_implicit_object_creation_when_type_is_apparent) that explains which style it prefers depending on `true` and `false` (without a type vs. without one); I don't think I could explain it more clearly myself. It is completely separate from the severity as it configures the actual style to prefer -- it will trigger if you *haven't* specified a type or when you *have* specified a type, depending on the setting. The remaining options just widen the scope for disabling.

Comment: @JeroenMostert apologies, it's not very clear what the difference is between setting the bool option to false vs. setting the severity to None. It just struck me as strange why there would be two ways to suppress the editor squiggle and build warning. I was probably overthinking and assuming there must have been more to the bool option.

Comment: I'm a big detractor of these kinds of switches myself; if the setting allowed things like `prefer_type` vs `prefer_no_type` that would be miles better than `true` or `false`. I'm going to be charitable and guess that using a `bool` is simpler because integrating a custom enum into the parser is more work, but I might be wrong and it could just be laziness.

Comment: Analyzers can produce more than one style suggestion/error which is why you get the option to turn off _just_ IDE0090, but in this case the `csharp_style_implicit_object_creation_when_type_is_apparent` style analyzer only produces one. There's really no difference between turning the analyzer off (`false`) vs settings it's severity to none. You can also do this in your editorconfig: `csharp_style_implicit_object_creation_when_type_is_apparent = true:warning
`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. In this case `false` *is* the same as turning it off -- you don't force warnings for *not* using target-typed new with `false`, and so the severity does nothing at all. Nice.